# Unreal: flipping a model by negating the scale along x-axis?

Tags: 3d, scale, axis, unreal-engine4

Basically, I went to make a variation of a model that is flipped along the x-axis. After I negate the x scale in the Blueprint it interferes with rotation and flips the x and z rotation.

I understand that negating the scale flips the normals and is bad practice for creating a variation in general. In Unity, it's frowned upon as well, but I've seen it in many standard packages that need both left and right prefabs of objects. Rotation has never which been affected by negating the scale in Unity.

Is there an Unreal equivalent without creating 2 models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've learned that the best fix is just using another model, since negatively scaling a mesh component can break internal collision in Unreal.

I had a rigged FBX, but Blender made it very easy to mirror along the X-axis and export the new model.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A bit of hack: you can make empty SceneComponent and add your model to it as a child. SceneComponent rotation will not be affected, and you'll have more control on your child model